Replacing subject pronoun with object pronoun?
Saw this excerpt in L'Étranger:

Masson et moi, nous avons attendu un peu. Lui parlait lentement et j'ai remarqué qu'il avait l'habitude de compléter tout ce qu'il avançait par un « et je dirai plus », même quand, au fond, il n'ajoutait rien au sens de sa phrase.

The Lui is where I would have expected to see Il.
Now, I've seen things like this:


To emphasize contrast or identity:
“Lui, il est gentil, mais son frère ne l’est pas.”
In literary or poetic French:
“Lui qui aimait tant voyager…”


But this case is different. This isn't Lui qui... or Lui, il est... It's just Lui + verb and that is new to me.
So why Lui there instead of Il? What is the nuance of meaning added by this, and when is it grammatically viable to make this replacement?

C'est le cas 1 que tu décris. L'emploi du pronom lui sert à mettre en valeur le sujet il qui est sous-entendu. On peut comprendre de façon implicite que le narrateur, lui, ne parle pas lentement.
Tous les pronoms toniques peuvent être employés seuls comme sujets sauf toi et moi. C'est à dire que « moi parlais lentement et .... » ne serait pas possible.  À ce sujet voir cette question : « Lui » peut être sujet, mais pas « moi » ?
